# Issue with Android Table Layout with two rows and right align

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I'm having a problem with Android layout.. what I'm trying to create is something similar to this:

```
<table width="300px">
    <tr>
        <td span="2">test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">image1</td>
        <td align="right">image2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Except I'd want "image1" and 2 to be together. Anyways,

Here is the layout I'm using in Android:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow android:layout_gravity="left" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:paddingRight="5dip"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="13dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_gravity="right" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50px"
            android:layout_height="120px"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="263px"
            android:layout_height="150px"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

I have also tried putting android:layout_gravity:"right" on the ImageViews themselves, which did nothing.

For some reason, this Android layout always indents the label (it doesn't span the columns), and never right aligns anything in the second row.. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. This is Android 2.1. Anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this with this kind of layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="13dip" />

    <TableLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow android:gravity="right" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50px"
                android:layout_height="120px"
                android:layout_column="1" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="263px"
                android:layout_height="150px"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:paddingRight="20dip" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also, another problem was that I am setting width/height by pixels in code, depending on what I need, and when you do that you wipe out the column as well.. so the code had to be something like:

```
        abc = new TableRow.LayoutParams(myImageWidth,
                mykpiImageHeight);
        abc.column = 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok My answer is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

          <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textid"
                android:text="SOME TEXT"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingRight="5dip"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="13dip" />

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/cloud1"
                android:id="@+id/imageview1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/textid"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/grey_bar"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/imageview1"
                android:layout_width="263dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

There are a few other poitners too:

- Do not use PX use dp, this is for density independent pixels (see [What is the difference between "px", "dp", "dip" and "sp" on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android))
- Do not use inline colours for the final product put them in res/values/colors, however I am sure you know this
- Rename the Id's I added along with removing "android:text" and "android:src" attributes as they were put in to simply show you.

Comment: i will try this. as for using px, actually the images coming back are based on the device's pixel width, so i change the height/width based on this, which is why i use pixels (images generated on server based on device pixels available). the rest you are right, but it was all taken out for brevity sake

Comment: so i tried this, it actually bunched everything up on top of each other. i did find the solution though, in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

It is confirmed a bug in ADT and is believed to be fixed in ADT 21.  See [bug fixed - at end](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=32849)